# Intercept an async action in redux

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm building a simple notes app using react with redux. My create notes action looks like this:

```
import axios from "axios";

const URL = 'http://localhost:3002/api/';

export function createNote(data = {}) {
    return {
        type: 'CREATE_NOTE',
        payload: axios.post(URL + 'notes/', data),
    };
}
```

And I've got the following in my reducer:

```
    // Create
    case 'CREATE_NOTE_PENDING':
    {
        return {
            ...state,
            creating: true
        };
    }

    case 'CREATE_NOTE_FULFILLED':
    {
        return {
            ...state,
            creating: false,
            notes: action.payload.data
        };
    }

    case 'CREATE_NOTE_REJECTED': {
        return {
            ...state,
            creating: false,
            error: action.payload
        };
    }
```

And this is my Notes class:

```
function mapStateToProps(store) {
    return {
        data: store.note.notes,
        fetching: store.note.fetching,
        creating: store.note.creating,
        error: store.note.error,
    };
}

class Notes extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(fetchNotes());
    }

    create() {
        this.props.dispatch(createNote({
            title: this.refs.title.value,
            content: this.refs.content.value,
        }));

        this.refs.title.value = '';
        this.refs.content.value = '';
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <h1 className="text-center">Notepad</h1>
                <div className="row">

                    <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input ref="title" placeholder="Create a note" className="form-control" disabled={this.props.creating} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <textarea ref="content" className="form-control" disabled={this.props.creating} />
                        </div>
                        <button onClick={this.create.bind(this)}
                                type="submit"
                                className="btn btn-primary"
                                style={{float: 'right'}}
                                disabled={this.props.creating} >Save</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

No on create I'm going to disable the form till I get an answer from the server and reset the content inside the form. My question is **how to reset the content of the form when I've got response**, i.e. when the form is enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to control the content of input and textarea, you should use controlled components. That is to provide a value attribute to, e.g. input

```
<input value={this.state.title} placeholder="Create a note" className="form-control" disabled={this.props.creating} />
```

You can use either internal state or redux state for the value. Then you are able to control the value by setState or redux actions.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful! Thank you!